# ERROR : Syntax error in expression (unexpected `|')

Tags: haskell

Ι want to achieve this structure in lists

```
Main> update 1 []
[1]
Main> update 2 [2]
[2]
Main> update 6 [1,2,5,8]
[1,2,5,8,6]
Main> 7 [7,7,7,3,4,5,8]
[3,4,5,8,7]
-}
```

and my code is ,

```
update :: Int->[Int]->[Int]

update n s  
    = update1 n s


update1 :: Int->[Int]->[Int] 
update1 n (h:t)
    | h==[] =  n: 
    | n==h = update1 n t 
    | otherwise = h : update1 n t
```

***Where*** and ***why*** am i wrong ?

Comment: `n:` is not a valid expression. `(n:)` is, but it won't type-check...

Comment: I fixed it, but now I have another error. How exactly should I check _If the head is empty_ ?

Comment: If you have a new problem ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `n:` is not correct. What you want to do is instead return `[n]` or `n:[]`. Also you can use pattern matching to check for the empty case:

```
update1 :: Int->[Int]->[Int] 
update1 n [] = [n]
update1 n (h:t)
    | n == h = update1 n t 
    | otherwise = h : update1 n t
```